# does a scheduled timer automatically get deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I'm using the following NSTimer class method:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
 3, 
 target: self, 
 selector: Selector("setWaitThreeSecondsFalse"), 
 userInfo: nil, 
 repeats: false
)
```

does the returned timer get deallocated after the selector runs? or do I have to explicitly invalidate the timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-repeating timer like you have will invalidate itself once it fires. So you do not need to do anything in this case unless you wish to invalidate it before it fires.

From the docs for `NSTimer`:

> Once scheduled on a run loop, the timer fires at the specified interval until it is invalidated. A non-repeating timer invalidates itself immediately after it fires.

As long as you don't have a strong reference to the timer, it will be deallocated after it is invalidated.

Answer (score 5):

From Apple documentation:

> Timers work in conjunction with run loops. To use a timer effectively,
>   you should be aware of how run loops operate—see NSRunLoop and
>   Threading Programming Guide. Note in particular that run loops
>   maintain strong references to their timers, so you don’t have to
>   maintain your own strong reference to a timer after you have added it
>   to a run loop.

Since run loop holds a string reference to `NSTimer` object, you must invalidate `NSTimer` to remove it from the run loop.

**Edit**
This apparently is valid for repeating timers. Non-repeating gets auto invalidate as rmaddy pointed out!

Comment: But a non-repeating timer invalidates itself after its one firing so there is no need to explicitly invalidate a non-repeating timer.

Comment: @rmaddy I haven't seen this in Apple documentation. Could you please point me to the link where this is mentioned. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: The info is in my answer. It's from the description of the `NSTimer` class under the "Scheduling Timers in Run Loops" section.